# ASP.NET MVC2 -- How is Html.Encode() used?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html.encode

How is Html.Encode() used? What is its purpose, and how is it useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It HTML encodes the passed it text - this escapes things to avoid certain types of attacks, such as [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

For example:

```
Html.Encode("<script>alert('hi');</alert>")
```

Will result in:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert('hi');&lt;/script&gt;
```

Being output to the page. This ensures that the script will **not** run.

Answer (score 0):

It encodes tags found in text into their html equiv. For example if '&' was received it would be changed into `'&amp;'`

Hope this helps.